# Setting default Python grammar version in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have a fresh installation of Eclipse and PyDev, on a Mac that has Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 installed. Whenever I start a new PyDev project, it asks me to choose a grammar version, and 2.7 is the default. How can I change it so 3.6 is the default grammar?

In Eclipse preferences -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter I only have Python 3.6 configured; where else should I look?

[image: Eclipse preferences screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not implemented (albeit it really should use the current interpreter selected to define the default version, so, please report this in the pydev tracker: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev)