# How to add a new Pydev Interpreter in Eclipse

Tags: python, pydev

Ok so I have Pydev installed on 2 machines.  For some reason I have 3.5.1 on a laptop and 2.7 on the desktop.  Now a project I have on the 2.7 machine (desktop) throws syntax errors on the other machine (laptop), which I guess must be because they are running different versions of Python, since I can't see any other possible cause.  As such, I installed 2.7 on the laptop, but before attempting to change the default interpreter to 2.7 (which I may or may not have done correctly: I just added the 2.7 path and moved it to the top of the list of (2) interpreters) I tried fiddling with the launch preferences in an effort to make it work.  Now when I try running the project, I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiFoi.jpg

I tried googling things like 'how to add new interpreter in PyDev' but didn't find anything which helped.  Anyone know what on earth is going and how I might get the project which works fine on the desktop working on the laptop as well?

I've noticed in this question:

[Setting default Python grammar version in Eclipse PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165453/setting-default-python-grammar-version-in-eclipse-pydev)

that it basically asks what may be the same thing (although I'm not sure the result I get which I showed in the imgur link is actually to do with the Python version so this problem may not be the same as that in the other question I linked: it seems I may have 2 problems: 1 which is similar to that in the question I linked and a new 1 (shown in the imgur link, at the bottom, where it says 'Ran 0 tests in 0.000 s) possibly caused by fiddling with the launch preferences).  My question is how to proceed on the laptop so that I can make the project work.  Could I do this by removing Python 3.5.1?  Is it not possible to have 2 different versions of Python on the same machine and to choose which you use for each given project?  If it is possible, how do you do this?  I actually tried removing 3.5.1 from the interpreters but the result is the same and when I checked the interpreters again, 3.5.1 was still there, so I would also like to know how to remove an interpreter.  Everything about this seems so incredibly awkward.  Genuinely have no idea why things should be make so awkard.

Edit: I think I've successfully changed the interpreter that's being used, thanks to Joe, but I still get the useless result when I run that I posted in the imgur link.  It looks like it's running a 'Python unit-test' (whatever that is) and I want to restore it to what it used to do, which was just a standard run. Any ideas appreciated.

Edit 2: turns out it just runs as whatever you last ran it as, by default and no option to change this, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course this is possible:

Eclipse - Windows - Preferences - PyDev - Interpreters - Python Interpreter - New...

Then you can seelct the interpreter per project:

Right-click project - Properties - PyDev-Interpreter/Grammar - Interpreter - Pick from list

Comment: Thanks for your response, but when I right-Click project and click PyDev I don't see any option 'Interpreter/Grammar'.

Comment: I updated the answer, you need to go to "properties" of the project

Comment: Yeah thanks that works but I still get  the useless result when I run that I posted in the imgur link.  It looks like it's running a 'Python unit-test' (whatever that is) and I want to restore it to what it used to do, which was just a standard run.  Any ideas appreciated.  I've upvoted you reply as it helped, bu tnot accepted it as answer yet as the problem is still not yet totally solved.

Comment: Save the file as BarCodeTest.py to get correct syntax highlighting. Then make your you are not running as unit test: `Eclipse - Run - Run as - Python run`

Comment: Thanks.  That works, but can I get it to run as a normal run (rather than a unit test) by default when i click the green arrow?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "useless result"? The console output? Or the editor window?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164100/discussion-between-george-tomlinson-and-joe).

Answer (score 1):

As a note, it seems the files in your screenshot aren't .py files (i.e.: it's `BarCodeTest` when it should be `BarCodeTest.py`), so, you don't have syntax highlighting nor anything associated to the PyDev editor.

After you change the file to a `.py` file, you should be able to just use `F9` to run the current file. The getting started manual: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html has more information on ways to properly run a module.

Comment: Yes thanks Joe noticed my failure to add the .py, after which it was still running a unit test (not what I wanted) by default, but I found out how to run it normally.  Apparently pressing the green triangle which usually runs programs in the normal way defaults to the last way you ran it (a unit test in my case, althouogh I hadn't intended to do this).  Anyway thanks for the info about F9 and the link to the manual.

Comment: Note that for running unit-tests, you should use `Ctrl+F9` instead of just `F9` (this is in http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_run.html, but I thought it may be interesting to point it out).